# sum of exponentials with modulus function

Tags: summation, modular-arithmetic, exponential-sum

does anyone know how I can simplify this summation
\begin{multline}\sum_{k=1}^{K}\sum_{l=0}^{L-1}\exp\left(\frac{-j3\pi((n-(u-1)L)_N)^2}{N}\right)\exp\left(\frac{j3\pi((n-2-(u-1)L)_N)^2}{N}\right)\\\exp\left(\frac{j3\pi((-l+n-(k-1)L)_N)^2}{N}\right)\exp\left(\frac{-j3\pi((-l+n-2-(k-1)L)_N)^2}{N}\right)\end{multline}

$u$ is an integer between $1$ and $K$ and $n$ is an integer between $0$ and $N-1$. $(x)_N$ is the modulo function with divisor $N$.

Thanks

Comment: What ${}$is $ j $?

Comment: $j$ is used for complex numbers. Some use $i$ instead @Bernard

Comment: I see: mathematically, it's $i$. $j$ is an engineering notation – an unhappy notation, since mathematically, $j$ is often used to denote one of the non-real cube roots of unity ($\dfrac{-1+i\sqrt 3}2$).